# How to remove the JavaScript facet from an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, facet

In most cases I see it impossible to remove the JavaScript facet from an Eclipse project. The IDE simply doesn't allow me to clear the flag in the facet editor.

Why is it so? Is there any help/workaround?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To remove the JavaScript facet, right click on the JavaScript facet, and select Unlock. Then you can remove it and give the project a try.

Comment: Why does it lock it to begin with?